# SQL server stored procedures documentation

Tags: sql, windows, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

Does anyone know where I can get SQL server documentation pertaining to writing stored procedures (SQL Server 2008 R2)?

I Tried browsing [SQL Server 2000 Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee229584%28v=SQL.10%29.aspx) but find it very hard to use with links scattered all over the place.

I am particularly interested with built in functions (T-SQL), that includes examples, maybe in a pdf form also ?

Comment: I think that this is as close one would expect from a MSDN reference.

Comment: It's been quite a while the answer here tenfour. I could mark your post as an answer as soon as it's marked as an answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a list of built-in functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174318.aspx) on MSDN. Get used to using MSDN; it's a great reference but you have to learn its quirks.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2003/stored-procedures-basics/) is a good article about stored procedures, i guess it will give you some useful info.

Comment: not too bad. But I was thinking more to an approach for a professional developer. And it does not make links into any other online articles/documentation out there :-)

Comment: Not really I am not an addept of video lessons, they are not very good for coding usually, and I don't have the time to look at them :-). Plain old reading is far better :-)